# how to use multiple keys to select certain rows

Tags: r, data.table

For example, I have such data.table

```
library(data.table)

test <- data.table(x=c(rep(c(1:3),3)),y=c("A","B","A","C","C","B","B","B","A"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i90Pz.png)

I set two keys,x and y`setkey(test,x,y)`;

then i want to select the rows which "x"==1 or 2 and "y" =="A" or "B";

but if i input `test[list(c(1,2),c("A","B"))]`
i wrongly got [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxXXl.png)

how can i get what i want ,thx!!!

Comment: ok,thx!!! I got it.

Comment: one more question;;;if i have a colume named "Time",and i want to select the rows which the "time" is between 90000 to 120000, how can i do it . i use 90000:120000,i can't get what i want. Must i use between?